# Obtain the link under the href tag from different htmls with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing different searches in a web page and I want to obtain from each of the search the links that are under the href tag.
The part of the html that  I am interested in looks like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style='width:. 507px; height: 20px;' colspan='2'>
      <a href='https://www.webpage.com/CompanyCard?982387dhsdfi83123+Ltd.' target='_blank'> 123.Ltd.
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

The problem is that since the html page is changing with every search I am not able to locate the page to do it with beautifulsoup.

I tried this so far but is not working:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
df=pd.read_excel('/Users/ap/list.xlsx')
opts = Options()
browser = Firefox(options=opts)
browser.get('https://www.webpage.com/')
for rows in df['firm']:  
    search_form1=browser.find_element_by_id('dnn_Search_tbSearch')
    search_form1.send_keys(rows)
    time.sleep(2)
    search_form2=browser.find_element_by_id('dnn_Search_lbGo').click()

    html = BeautifulSoup.find_all('td', attrs={'style': 'width: 507px; height: 20px'})
    for td in html:
        a= td.find('a')['href']
        links.append(a)
    i=i+1
```

How can I extract only the complete link related to the href for each of the searches: 'https://www.webpage.com/CompanyCard?982387dhsdfi83123+Ltd.'??
**All of the links start always by: https://www.webpage.com/CompanyCard?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css [attribute = value selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with starts with operator specifying that href attribute must start with `https://www.webpage.com/CompanyCard?`

E.g.

```
links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href^="https://www.webpage.com/CompanyCard?"]')
```

you can pass the same pattern

```
[href^="https://www.webpage.com/CompanyCard?"]
```

to selenium `find_elements_by_css_selector`

```
links = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[href^="https://www.webpage.com/CompanyCard?"]')]
```